# How can I remove this cyclic class dependency?

Tags: java, listener, circular-dependency

I have an `Entity` interface, implementations of which can collide with each other.  I would like to add a `CollisionListener` that is invoked when the collision takes place, which will accept a `CollisionEvent` containing the two colliding entities.  Is there a way I can do this without a cyclic dependency between `Entity` and `CollisionListener`?

What I have currently:

```
public interface Entity {

    void addCollisionListener(CollisionListener listener);

    void getStrength();

    void dealDamage();

    void die();

    // Other methods
}

// To be implemented and added to Entities when you want to watch for collisions
public interface CollisionListener {
    void onCollision(CollisionEvent event);
}

public class CollisionEvent {
    private final Entity source, collider;

    public CollisionEvent(Entity source, Entity collider) {
        this.source = source;
        this.collider = collider;
    }

    public Entity getSource() { return source; }

    public Entity getCollider() { return collider; }
}
```

This has the following cyclical dependency:

`Entity -> CollisionListener -> CollisionEvent -> Entity`

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue (or if it even can be resolved) because implementations of the `CollisionListener` interface should have access to the `Entity` objects affected by the collision so that it can act on them (for example, calling the `dealDamage` or `die` methods.

I know that there's nothing strictly *wrong* with a cyclic dependency (i.e. the code compiles and runs fine), but I'd rather avoid them if at all possible.

Comment: What is the problem here? Java has no problems with classes that depend on each other. Do you need to keep the classes in separate libraries/projects?

Comment: You have entities that listen for colliding entities.  This is inherently going to be a bidirectional dependency.  You could get around this (if you really want to) by having an external resource (like a `CollisionHandler`) handle any collisions between entities, and then the entities don't need to know about the `CollisionListener` (IE: you can remove the `addCollisionListener()` method from `Entity`).

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* exactly with the two classes depending on one another, but I've always understood that this scenario makes the classes more fragile and more tightly coupled, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Tightly-coupled classes are classes that depend heavily on the implementation details of other **classes**, and thus cannot be considered individual elements.  This isn't really the case here; `Entity` knows that it has a `ConnectionListener`, but that is an interface with no concrete details associated with it (and, of course, vica versa is true).  You can easily test and develop Entity by mocking a ConnectionListener; the coupling is fairly loose (about as loose as you can get).

Comment: @Ironcache Ahhh I see what you're getting at.  Awesome, I really appreciate the insight.  Add as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `Entity` and `CollisionListener` know about each other isn't really a big deal; the cyclic dependencies mean that the two classes know about each other (which makes sense; it is a cohesive system).  However, **the two are not tightly-coupled**, as they know very little about external implementation details.

To make this concrete, consider if you were to design a unit test for an implementation of `Entity`.  You could very easily mock `CollisionListener` (using a resource like Mockito, or even just creating an implementation in the unit test, like `MockCollisionListener`).  `Entity` implementations do not depend on any external implementation details, and, as a result, is free to change implementations so long as the contractual interface (`CollisionListener`) is obeyed.

However, if you still do not want your resources to know about each other, consider the [Mediator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html), which basically just states that, rather than having resources talk to each other, you have a mediator object know about them, and handles communication between them.